# Get links from requests or beautifulsoup that are hidden inside the page

Tags: python, web-scraping

More general question since I do not think I have a complete enough code to post.
https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/main/data/database
This is the webpage I am interested in downloading every file that exists in the dropdown tree.
Problem is the links in the dropdown tree for files (provided by google chrome inspection) do
not seem to be visible by requests or beautifulsoup. Any advice on why is that and what should I do? Thanks in advance and I will provide every piece of code I have available if that helps.

Comment: That usually means that the html for those links are generated via JS. That doesn't run when using `requests`. Try using selenium to automate it instead.

Comment: No need to use selenium here, @rdas. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this *without* the heavy guns of selenium.

You can fake the `Ajax` request and get *all* the links to bulk downloads of all files for all folders.

Here's how to do it:

```python
import re

import requests

with requests.Session() as connection:
    _ = connection.get("https://ec.europa.eu")
    initial_response = connection.get(
        "https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/main/data/database",
    )
    ajax_url = re.search(
        r"sendAjaxRequest\('(.*?)',",
        initial_response.text,
    ).group(1)
    main_response = connection.get(ajax_url).text
    links = re.findall(r"href: '(https:.*?)',", main_response)
    for link in links:
        r = connection.get(link)
        file_name = r.headers["Content-Disposition"].split("=")[-1]
        print(f"Downloading: {file_name}")
        with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
            f.write(r.content)
```

This grabs all the `.zip` files that contain all the files per folder you see on the page.

```
NavTree_cei_en.zip
NavTree_es_en.zip
NavTree_sdg_en.zip
NavTree_shorties_en.zip
NavTree_t2020_en.zip
NavTree_tepsr_en.zip
NavTree_tips_en.zip
```

EDIT:

Alright, you were right that not all files were there but you didn't mention there's an *entire* section on Eurostat's page devoted to [bulk download](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/main/data/bulkdownload).

If you read their guide and check out some of the URLs you'll most likely end up [here](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/estat-navtree-portlet-prod/BulkDownloadListing).

Then you can go to `[data]` and, boom, there are *all* the files and their links.

You can order by `ALL` and scrape that.

You should end up with over `6700` files available for download.

Here's how to do it:

```python
import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def wait_a_bit(wait_for: float = 1.5):
    time.sleep(wait_for)


with requests.Session() as connection:
    endpoint = connection.get(
        "https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/estat-navtree-portlet-prod/"
        "BulkDownloadListing?dir=data&sort=1&sort=2&start=all"
    )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(endpoint.text, "lxml").find_all("a", {"rel": "external"})
    links = [a["href"] for a in soup]
    print(f"Found {len(links)} files.")

    for link in links[:10]:  # getting only first 10 files
        r = connection.get(link)
        file_name = (
            r.headers["Content-Disposition"]
            .split("=")[-1]
            .replace('"', "")
        )
        print(f"Downloading: {file_name}")
        with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
            f.write(r.content)
        wait_a_bit()
```

**NOTE:** I'm using a limiter here (fetching only the first 10 files), but if you *really* want to download ALL the files then change this:

```
    for link in links[:10]:  # getting only first 10 files
```

to this:

```
    for link in links:
```

Comment: Okay this is really close but still does not download everything. There are multiple files in the dropdown menu that do not show up.

Comment: How do you know how many files are there to be downloaded exactly? Do you have a list of files you want to get? These zip files are collections of files per branch of the folder tree from the page. Have you unpacked them and inspected the files?

Comment: Yes and they are not all of the files in this page. I need every single file there. For example if you go to Database by themes -> Industry, trade and services -> Tourism (tour) -> Monthly data on tourism industries (tour_indm) there are some .gz files that do not exist in the ones that you mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

As mention by @rdas the website you are trying to scape rendering the links after the page is loaded, it is probably using a modern JS front-end framework.

To extract the links from this website you can use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io) and wait for the website to render then extract all the links and parse them to get the ones you want. If all you want is to download the data you can also just open them and download the data (also with Selenium).

The code would look something like this:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

import time

options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

# Open the website
driver.get("https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/main/data/database")

# Wait for the page to load
time.sleep(5)

elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")

extracted_links = []

# Iterate over elements with hrefs
for elem in elems:
    # Condition to only get the links you want
    if (elem.get_attribute('href')).endswith(.tsv.gz)
        extracted_links.append(elem.get_attribute('href'))

print(extracted_links)
```

I hope this helped

Comment: Does that actually work for you? Because I get a return of empty array [].

Comment: No it’s an example of how the code should be